# How to use a gif as an animation in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, animation, android-animation

It's been sometime i'm trying to add an animation to my application they have many frame so i can't do it by a res like a small animation. And the resource i want to use is from gif files so i don't know how to convert or just use them so they can make an animation that happen sometime. it's for a character anmation.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Suggest you to use the Glide library.

Easy to use and apply gif assets.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide